# El valor del tipo especificado String del origen de datos no se puede convertir al tipo nvarchar de la columna de destino especificada SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel

Mi problema es el siguiente estoy queriendo pasar un archivo de excel a sql server. Cuando tomo el archivo y lo quiero pasar me tira este error:

> "El valor del tipo especificado String del origen de datos no se puede
>   convertir al tipo nvarchar de la columna de destino especificada".

Y por lo tanto no lo inserta en la base de datos.

Estoy intentando y no puedo hacer estar conversión

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar causando este error?

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    try
    {
        //string conexion = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source = C:/Users/dtorres/Desktop/Horamar/1131008.xlsx ;Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR = Yes\"";

        string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        path = path.Replace(" ", "");
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/ExcelFile/") + path);
        String Excelpath = Server.MapPath("/ExcelFile/") + path;

        string conexion = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source = " + Excelpath + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR = Yes\"";


        OleDbConnection origen = default(OleDbConnection);
        origen = new OleDbConnection(conexion);

        OleDbCommand seleccion = default(OleDbCommand);
        seleccion = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Hoja2$]", origen);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        adaptador.SelectCommand = seleccion;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adaptador.Fill(ds);


        grDatos.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grDatos.DataBind();

        origen.Close();


        SqlConnection conexion_destino = new SqlConnection();

        conexion_destino.ConnectionString = "Data Source = (Local); Integrated Security = True; Initial Catalog = openGL ";

        conexion_destino.Open();

        SqlBulkCopy importar = default(SqlBulkCopy);
        importar = new SqlBulkCopy(conexion_destino);
        importar.DestinationTableName = "mayorizacion";



        importar.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
        conexion_destino.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Label3.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: El origen del error está en los datos. Es posible que una de sus columnas "del excel" no tenga datos. Revise la tabla en SQL Server y compare la información del Excel. Revíselo bien porque puede que una de esas columnas tenga valores incorrectos.

Comment: Lo pude resolver! la columna era de tipo nvarchar(50) y se lo aumente y me lo tomo. GRACIAS!

Comment: que bueno que esa haya sido el origen del problema. Lo invito a [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El origen del error está en los datos.

Es posible que una de sus columnas "del excel" no tenga datos.

Revise la tabla en SQL Server y compare la información del Excel. Revíselo bien porque puede que una de esas columnas tenga valores incorrectos.

Tal como menciona en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207518/el-valor-del-tipo-especificado-string-del-origen-de-datos-no-se-puede-convertir?noredirect=1#comment387406_207518), era necesario aumentar el tamaño de la columna
a `nvarchar(50)`.