# Carga de datos de Excel a SQL Server mediante BulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

genere una aplicación Windows Forms, en la cual cargo datos de un archivo excel en formato csv y las inserto en SQL Server con BulkCopy, el problema surge cuando intento copiar un archivo con mas de 59000 registros, pues en el registro 25119 todo va bien, pero de ahí hasta el 59000 uno de los campos que yo defino como FK lo manda vacio, no se que pueda ser, alguno de ustedes que pueda ayudarme...
Se los agradezco...

Comment: Es posible que haya algún carácter extraño en el dato a importar.
Yo lo primero me aseguraría de que en la tabla SQL Server donde vas a insertar, todos los campos de texto son de tipo NVARCHAR(<ancho>) ya que así se tragará caracteres que no sean ASCII y que es posible que estén en el CSV. Si sigue sin funcionarte, crea una copia del CSV y elimina los registros del principio y del final hasta que encuentres el registro que falla y analizalo bien, seguramente haya algún caracter de salto de línea o especial.

Comment: Es gracioso porque ya lo hice, de hecho el documento lo dividí en 3 partes y las 3 partes en separado funciona a la perfección, no se si sea un problema de memoria o del datagried view, muchas gracias por el aporte...

Comment: Entonces es muy probable que sea por el tamaño del fichero. Es posible que el Event Viewer o en los Registros de SQL Server te de algún mensaje que te ayude.

Comment: ¿es posible que sea un problema de datos?, revisa esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/207585/78).